# Python converting , in requests.get parameters to %2C and '|' to %7C

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am using Google distance matrix API, with `python` to build distance matrix.
While using lat-long `,` and `|` symbols gets encoded in the URL resulting in invalid request.

Here's my code:

```
import requests
url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json'
params = {
   'origins' : '12.9571,77.659439|12.9353173134382,77.7402628734708',
   'key' : 'XXXXX'       # key hidden for security reasons
}
response = requests.get(url=url, params=params)
```

This returns a bad request.

when i try to print the requested URL,

```
response.url
```

output is

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=12.9571%2C77.659439%7C12.9353173134382%2C77.7402628734708&key=XXXX
```

As we can see, `|` and `,` are getting converted to `%2C` and `%7C`, making URL invalid. How can i get around this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `GET`, just format parameters in form of string `?key=val&...` and append to base URL:

```py
import requests

base_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json'
params = {
    'key': 'XXXXX',
    'origins': '12.9571,77.659439|12.9353173134382,77.7402628734708',
}

formatted_url = base_url + '?' + '&'.join(["{}={}".format(k,v) for k,v in params.items()])  # !
print(formatted_url)

response = requests.get(formatted_url)
...
```

Output:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?key=XXXXX&origins=12.9571,77.659439|12.9353173134382,77.7402628734708
```

I know it (`# !`) looks a bit ugly, but looks like that's the only solution for `GET` requests with query string.